# Spring Boot 2 use dev profile if prod profile is not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I have Spring Boot Application and i have 3 property files: `applications.properties, applications-dev.properties, applicaton-prod.properties`. In `applications.properties` i specify that `spring.profiles.active=prod`. But I want to allow startup of application without prod profile(`applicaton-prod.properties`). It means that spring must startup application in dev profile(`applications-dev.properties`) automatically. How can i implement this? May be some `MissingOnProfile` annotation exist?) My task is to create different application behaviour based on application.properties files. Also i use `@Profile` annotation in each bean that depends on particular profile. All task is to create WebInstaller, and in finish step i will create application-prod.properties and by using `RestartEndpoint` i will restart application context and required beans from `application-prod.properties` will injected. But i need to make startup withoud `application-prod.properties`, but if this file exist i will startup in prod profile.

Comment: “If prod profile is not exist”?? The point of spring profiles is you have one artifact you can promote from one env to the next, with all the profile configs present, using system properties or whatever to decide what profile is active in each env. There should not be a case where the prod profile properties file does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(IdMatrixApplication.class);
File file = new File("src/main/resources/dev/application-prod.properties");
if (file.exists()) {
    application.setAdditionalProfiles("prod","dev");
}
application.run(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the profile information in the wrong place. The file `application.properties` contains properties that are common to all profiles (dev, stage, prod etc). For profiles you should, as you suggested, create a file of the name `application-{profile}.properties` which will override certain properties according to the environemnt defined by variable `profile`.

The usual approach is to pass this variables as parameters to the JVM (e.g:`-Dprofile=dev`), which you can set by modifying the run configuration of the servlet container if you are launching from an IDE. In case of a stand-alone tomcat you can pass this information through `JAVA_OPTIONS` variable  found in the file `setenv.sh`.

Comment: i mean that i want to start my application in dev profile(using application-dev.properties) if application-prod.properties was not found. But by default my profile is prod(application-prod.properties). If i specify in application.properties that active profile is prod, and if application-prod.properties was not found in resources package my application failed to start. But i want to automaticaly switch to dev profile (application-dev.properties) if prod profile was not found. Because i want to dynamicaly add this file and restart all application in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manually implement some kind of business logic with profiles, for example, specify that the active profile by default `prod`

1. In `application.properties` define `spring.profiles.active=prod`

and for example if the `application-prod.properties` is missing, then the active profile should be the `dev`, you can implement this with `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

> Allows for customization of the application's Environment prior to the application context being refreshed

2. Implement `EnvironmentPostProcessor`  with your business logic

   ```
   public class ProfileResolverEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

   @Override
   public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
       ClassPathResource prodPropertiesResource = new ClassPathResource("application-prod.properties");
       // if "application-prod.properties" missing and "prod" profile active
       if (!prodPropertiesResource.exists() && environment.acceptsProfiles("prod")) {
           environment.setActiveProfiles("dev");
           //environment.addActiveProfile("dev");
       }
   }

   }
   ```
3. Register your `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation class in `META-INF/spring.factories`

`org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
 com.example.ProfileResolverEnvironmentPostProcessor`

> Also, take look at Spring Boot documentation [Customize the
>   Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)

Additional:

Of course, you can specify beans that will be active if the profile is missing `@Profile("!prod")`
But this does not work in your case if you define `spring.profiles.active=prod`, because the active profile `prod` will be in the `Environment` but it has nothing to do with the fact that the `application-prod.properties` is missing

Answer (score 0):

If you want this then why you need `application-dev.properties`. Keep Your dev properties in `application.properties`. If profile set then `applicatoin.properties` value will be overwrite. Spring boot read both `application.properties` && `application.yml` and replace value if profile active